# How do I synchronize scale and position of map and point layers in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, geo

I've seen many example maps in d3 where points added to a map automatically align as expected, but in code I've adapted from http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/3230965 the points I've added do not line up with the map below.

Example here: https://naltmann.github.io/d3-geo-collision/
(the points should match up with some major US cities)

I'm pretty sure the difference is due to the code around scale/range, but I don't know how to unify them between the map and points.

Comment: A force layout generally would imply that you are letting predefined forces position the elements at least to some extent, which in turn means that geographic accuracy is sacrificed. If you want each point to align with its coordinates, why not place them as so using their coordinates? I feel I am missing something in this question.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thanks for the reply. The code positions the points using coordinates and then uses collision logic to spread them out so they don't touch. This will move them from their true coordinates, but the problem I have is more basic than that. I seem to have 2 layers that have no coordinate relation to each other (scale, position, etc.). I tweaked some of the range/scale values to make them appear close, but they're not truly tied together like they should be. I think there's something basic about the way the svg is assembled by d3 that I'm mssing.

Comment: Ok, I did take a closer look, the approach strikes me as peculiar, I don't think I've ever seen scales for x and y to place geographic coordinates. There is likely a way to resolve this without scales. I'll try to examine this a bit more today - though I'm preoccupied with a bit of a flooding situation.

Comment: Thanks again. I've undoubtedly frankenstein'ed something pretty awful when trying to adapt from the original code. Good suggestion though, I'll see if I can strip out the x and y scale portions.

Comment: I hope my answer is useful, this was an interesting problem - and I like seeing different solutions to placement of markers such as yours (especially in relation to geographic label placement - something that proves an issue regularily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aligning geographic features geographically with your example will be challenging - first you are projecting points and then scaling x,y:

```
    node.cx = xScale(projection(node.coordinates)[0]);
    node.cy = yScale(projection(node.coordinates)[1]);
```

The ranges for the scales is interesting in that both limits of both ranges are negatives, this might be an attempt to rectify the positioning of points due to the cumulative nature of forces on the points:

```
            .on('tick', function(e) {
                k = 10 * e.alpha;
                for (i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                nodes[i].x += k * nodes[i].cx  
                nodes[i].y += k * nodes[i].cy
```

This is challenging as if we remove the scales, the points move farther and farther right and down. This cumulative nature means that with each tick the points drift further and further from recognizable geographic coordinates. This is fine when dealing with a set of geographic data that undergoes the same transformation, but when dealing with a background that doesn't undergo the same transformation, it's a bit hard.

*I'll note that if you want a map width of 1800 and a height of 900, you should set the mercator projection's translate to `[1800/2,900/2]` and the scale to something like `1800/Math.PI/2`*

The disconnection between geographic coordinates and force coordinates appears to be very difficult to rectify. Any solution for this particular layout and dimensions is likely to fail on different layouts and dimensions.

Instead I'd suggest attempting to use only a projection to place coordinates and not cumulatively adding force changes to each point. This is the short answer to your question.

For a longer answer, my first thought was to get rid of the collision function and use an anchor point linked to a floating point for each city, only drawing the floating point (using link distance to keep them close). This is likely a cleaner solution, but one that is unfortunately completely different than what you've attempted.

However, my second thoughts were more towards keeping your example, but removing the scales (and the cumulative forces) and reducing the forces to zero so that the collision function can work without interference. Based on those thoughts, here's a [demonstration](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/3b6132d369360c4f6a37833f985f0cbb) of a possible solution.